# nose runs test on function in setUp when no suite specified

Tags: python, pyramid, nose

I have a tests file in one of my Pyramid projects. It has *one* suite with *six* tests in it:

```
...
from .scripts import populate_test_data

class FunctionalTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        settings = appconfig('config:testing.ini',
                             'main',
                             relative_to='../..')
        app = main({}, **settings)
        self.testapp = TestApp(app)
        self.config = testing.setUp()
        engine = engine_from_config(settings)
        DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
        populate_test_data(engine)

    def tearDown(self):
        DBSession.remove()
        tearDown()

    def test_index(self):
        ...

    def test_login_form(self):
        ...

    def test_read_recipe(self):
        ...

    def test_tag(self):
        ...

    def test_dish(self):
        ...

    def test_dashboard_forbidden(self):
        ...
```

Now, when I run `nosetests templates.py` (where `templates.py` is the mentioned file) I get the following output:

```
......E
======================================================================
ERROR: templates.populate_test_data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yentsun/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/yentsun/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 622, in newfunc
    return func(*arg, **kw)
TypeError: populate_test_data() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 1.985s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

When I run the tests with test suite specified `nosetests templates.py:FunctionalTests`, the output is, as expected, ok:

```
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 1.980s

OK
```

Why do I have different output and why is an extra (7th) test run?

**UPDATE.** Its a bit frustrating, but I when removed the word *test* from the name `populate_test_data` (it became `populate_dummy_data`), everything worked fine.

The problem is solved for now, but maybe somebody knows what went wrong here - why a function from `setUp` had been tested?

Comment: you are calling the populate_test_data function wrong.

Comment: Try running nose with `verbosity = 3` so that you can see the names of the tests that are running. Should help.

Comment: @Wesley Baugh: Thanks for the hint. The verbose output shows that `populate_test_data` is tested and fails(`templates.populate_test_data ... ERROR`). Investigating further...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Finding and running tests**
>
> nose, by default, follows a few simple rules for test discovery.
>
> - If it looks like a test, it’s a test. Names of directories, modules, classes and functions are compared against the **testMatch regular
>     expression**, and those that match are considered tests. Any class that
>     is a unittest.TestCase subclass is also collected, so long as it is
>     inside of a module that looks like a test.

(from [nose 1.3.0 documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html))

In the nose's code, the regexp is defined as `r'(?:^|[\b_\.%s-])[Tt]est' % os.sep`, and if you inpect `nose/selector.py`, method `Selector.matches(self, name)` you'll see that the code uses [re.search](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), which looks for a match anywhere in the string, not only at the beginning, as `re.match` does.

A small test:

```
>>> import re
>>> import os
>>> testMatch = r'(?:^|[\b_\.%s-])[Tt]est' % os.sep
>>> re.match(testMatch, 'populate_test_data')
>>> re.search(testMatch, 'populate_test_data')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f3512569238>
```

So `populate_test_data` indeed "looks like a test" by nose's standards.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey, its now clear. Still, I am strongly convinced that there is no reason for a function in a fixture method, no matter what it 'looks like', to be tested. Or... is it possible that someone would want to run a test as a setup for another test?

Comment: @yentsun: I'm not sure why you refer to `populate_test_data` as "a function from setUp" - by importing it you created a module-level function in your test module. The function name matches the pattern node expects - no wonder nose considered it a test. Try doing something like `from .scripts import populate_dummy_data; populate_test_data = populate_dummy_data` to see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I got it now. Will be carefull with naming next time.